# TypeError [CLIENT-MISSING-INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've searched all other articles/threads regarding this issue, and all of the things I've done so far are the following:

1. Verified that my current Node.js version is v18.1.0
2. Confirmed that my bot.js file contains the following:

   ```
   const { Client, Intents }=require("discord.js");
   const client = new Client({
       Intents:[
           Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,  
           Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES  
       ]
   });
   ```
3. Enabled these 3 intent options  on my discord application:
   [image]

And I still get the error:

[image]

Here is my bot.js code:

```
require("DOTENV").config(); //to start process from .env file

const { Client, Intents }=require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
    Intents:[
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,//adds server functionality
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES //gets messages from our bot.
    ]
});

client.once("ready", () =>{
    console.log("BOT IS ONLINE"); //message when bot is online
})
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get your error because of a typo when you declare your client. When declaring the intents, you use this:

```js
const client = new Client({
    Intents: []
})
```

Instead of a capital I in the `Intents`, it should be small like this:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [] // Put your intents here
})
```

This is why you should always go through your code just to check the spelling of the words and if they need to be uppercase or lowercase